# Specific String auto increment in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to create a unique id for table Emp in MySQL like "Emp_0416_1", "Emp_0416_2" and "Emp_0516_1", "Emp_0516_2".

Here

```
 Emp is stand for Employee,
 04 is April month,
 16 is year,
 1 is emp code.
```

And

```
 Emp is stand for Employee,
 05 is May month,
 16 is year,
 1 is emp code.
```

Table is :

```
      create table emp (
          id varchar(20),
          name varchar(20)
      );
```

When I insert the emp name then it will auto increment like above unique id.

Comment: its not to difficult....have you tried  anything for it

Comment: do you want this string in procedure or single query??

Comment: @Jordan: I have no idea about it. I am new to mysql.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246078/how-do-i-create-an-index-from-a-stored-procedure-or-create-index-on-every-table and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242597/how-do-i-create-an-index-inside-a-stored-procedure . Possible duplicate.

Comment: using Generated Columns to solve your stuff

Comment: I want to create the procedure.

Comment: Maybe you need to re-word the question, but I thought you want different names for tables using a stored procedure. If you want strings for the `id` that you create, I would say you should design the database differently and create the table like `create table emp
    (
       id integer, month integer, year integer, employee_id integer,
       name varchar(20)
    );` and select from the table with `select *, concat('Emp_', month, year, '_', employee_id) as my_id from emp;`

Comment: You will want to use triggers in that case. Or else you can set the id from the java program when inserting

Comment: your emp_code will be auto increment or user specific??

Comment: It will generate the unique id but not auto incremented ?

Comment: I want auto_incremented.

Answer (score 0):

here is your desired solution

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_name`(in emp_code int,in emp_name varchar(256),in_date date)
        BEGIN
                declare temp_date varchar(256);
                set temp_date=  (select concat(
                                                 if(length(month(in_date))>1,month(in_date),concat(0,month(in_date))),right(year(in_date),2)
                                              ) as dateyear
                                 );

                INSERT into table_name(id,`name`) 
                select concat('emp_',temp_date,'_',emp_code)as emp_id,emp_name;



        END
```

**call procedure**

```
 call proc_name(2,'batman','2016-04-11')
```